# Can a medical student get an expedited certification as a paramedic?

Tags: practice-of-medicine, health-education, legal, united-states, european-union

Medical students, as future doctors, are in a rather unique position to support themselves in a part-time job in the medical field that provides a decent amount of on-call study time while also granting experience in many of the same skills that would be needed as a doctor. However, EMT and paramedic certification seem to require taking their own certification courses, while a medical student with a decent amount of studying should be able to pass any paramedic exam, and perform to a comparable standard to a trained paramedic.

Do opportunities for medical students to receive expedited paramedic certification while training to be doctors exist?

Comment: By medical student do you mean a student who's not yet an MD or do you include residents? If it's the former the answer is not in any state I'm aware of. You might be underestimating the amount of practical skills required, especially at the paramedic level.

Comment: To add to @CareyGregory: MedSchool is 6 years, paramedic is 3 years, and it is totally different. So no, it isn't likely. What is far more likely for med students are tedious tasks in hospitals: Assisting in surgery (that's what the ads show you), being a ill-equipped nurse for 12 patients in a night shift and stuff like that. Once you are a MD, it is in some legislations illegal for you to work as a paramedic because legally doctors are allowed and required to do more than paramedics, but since they work as paramedics, they'd violate all the guidelines, so until you become a so-called

Comment: emergency doctor (which is a special field, at least in Germany), as an MD you are in a sort of limbo where even as a certified paramedic, you may not work as one!

Comment: Also, for a med student who hasn't been through residency yet, they would be unlikely to have the practical skill set of a paramedic. In the US that includes intubation, rapid sequence intubation, cricothyrotomy, IV infusion, intraosseous infusion, chest decompression, EKG interpretation, manual defibrillation, synchronized cardioversion, extrication techniques, splinting, bandaging, bleeding control, and the administration of 40-50 drugs. There's no way you're going to expedite all those skills.

Comment: Not that I know of in the USA. @CareyGregory is correct that there is a VAST skillset involved in paramedic training, like nursing, and it only partially overlaps with what an MD or DO learns, depending on the subspecialty the physician goes into.  There ARE emergency departments that employ medical students as in-training emergency technicians INSIDE the ED, where they take on the responsibility for training you, but that's as far as I have ever heard.  Besides, paramedic training would definitely not be a part-time thing you could complete in the "spare time' during med school.

Comment: @CareyGregory back when I was a medical student, we went through provider ACLS training before starting 3rd year. This completely freaked out a number of my classmates who thought that meant they were supposed to be able to run a code in their first clinical rotation. Obviously, it was quite different on the floors. (You watch, unless someone tells you to do something very specific). Theoretically, 3rd year medical students have knowledge of all of these things (and have been tested on that knowledge), but little to no practical experience, and can't be trusted to do anything independently.

Comment: @DeNovo I figured ACLS was in the curriculum, but like you said, having to actually run a code is a lot different than practicing on a CPR dummy. It's the same for EMS providers. Paramedics usually get a fair amount of clinical time in an ED before they're out on the streets, and then they usually ride as a third for at least a few weeks and that's where the real training happens. Running a code in an ED under bright lights with RNs and techs to assist is one thing, but doing the same in somebody's bathroom at 0300 with vomit all over the floor is another.